# C dereference an integer pointer in a structure

Tags: c

I am having a problem correctly dereferencing a pointer to an integer that resides in an array of structures. The relevant parts of the code are:

```
typedef struct hf_register_info {
  int                   *p_id;  /**< written to by register() function */
  header_field_info     hfinfo; /**< the field info to be registered */
} hf_register_info;
.
.
hf_register_info hf[MAX_HF_COUNT];
.
.
*(hf[i].p_id) = -1;
```

The final line of code above causes an exception.  How do I correctly deference p_id?

Thanks and regards...Paul

Comment: Yes, the syntax is correct, you can also remove the parantheses. Where does `p_id` point to?

Comment: Do the pointer actually point anywhere valid? Otherwise dereferencing the pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Why are you assuming those are the only relevant parts of the code? I mean, if you already know what the problem is, why are you asking here?

Comment: use a debugger to inspect that p_id has a valid value that points to a place to store an int. My guess is that you dont mean `int *` , you really want `int`

Comment: Why do you need a pointer if you initializate it as it isn't? You should initializate the pointer to the address of some int variable first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your pointers. You pointers in your structs aren't pointing to anything at the moment you initialize your array.

So for every struct in your array you want to dereference your pointer and assign a value to, you'll need to allocate space in your memory first.

```
hf_register_info hf[MAX_HF_COUNT];

// some code here

hf[i].p_id = malloc(sizeof(int)); // or unsigned long or whatever
*(hf[i].p_id) = -1;
```